# Xamarin Form Prism Region Show Empty Page

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Below is one of my xaml file in my project. I was trying to create a region so that I can navigate a view into the region. However, when I added the code `<ContetnView BorderColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion"/>` and run it, a blank page was seen instead. When I remove the code line, I was able to view my controls. What is the root cause of this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MultiPosApp.Views.HomePageView">
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <Button Text="View A" Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="RegionAView"/>
                <Button Text="View B" Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="RegionBView"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <ContetnView BorderColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion"/>
        </Grid>
       
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Did you copy this code from your page? There is a typo in `ContetnView`.

Comment: Opp accidently editted, it should be ContentView. But in my source code was correct word, yet still facing still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the `App.xaml.cs` file in the `RegisterTypes` method add line `containerRegistry.RegisterRegionServices();`.

```cs
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
  containerRegistry.RegisterRegionServices();
  // ... other registrations
}
```